# How to hide some detail in html form when radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating student registration form as shown in the image:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
<tr><td><input type="radio"  checked="checked" name="rad1"> Pursuing <input type="radio" name="rad1"/> Completed </td></tr>


<tr><td align="right"><label>Avarage CPI * : </label></td>


<td><input type="number" name="cpi" step="0.01" />upto<input type="number" name="semester"/>th semester</td>


</tr>
```

Now if user selects "Completed" then upto ____ th semester should be disappeared as shown in following image.

[image: after "completed is selected"]

How can i do it? Should I use "onchange()" or "onselect()" event? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asku's answer won't behave as expected, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UxqFR/2/)

- it'll hide the semester upon when selecting pursing.
- if the user selects one radio that hides the semester and then select the other one, semester won't be displayed again.

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UxqFR/)

the code should be -

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByName('rad1')[0].onchange = function () {

    document.getElementById('semester').style.display = 'initial';
  }
  document.getElementsByName('rad1')[1].onchange = function () {

    document.getElementById('semester').style.display = 'none';

  }
}
```

Comment: @krupal it prints the value in developer console, its for debugging purpose, ignore it. would be nice if you accept the answer if it solved the issue.

Comment: Be sure that I will accept your answer but last and final question: how to disappear "Th semester" at that moment?

Comment: which moment? it's disappearing in this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UxqFR/ as far as i can see..

Comment: Ya..Its working but not in google chrome...The label "Th semester" is still not disappearing.

Comment: @krupal i'm also using chrome. its working in the fiddle. its not working in the fiddle or your page? make sure that 'th semester' is inside the  `<span>`